# Django-debug-toolbar not showing error 403 forbidden

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar, amazon-s3

I was trying to use django-debug-toolbar but it doesnt show up at all, so i tried inspecting my page and i found out theres actually a erro 403 forbidden that is hiding the toolbar. I've tried everything i knew and searched on the internet like a maniac but what solved someone elses problem wasnt working for me. Sorry if the code is hard to understand, i'm still a novice programmer. If any other information is required pelase let me know

settings.py:

```
import mimetypes
from functools import partial

import dj_database_url

from primeiraAplicacaoDjango import base # noqa
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config, Csv
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', cast=bool)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=Csv())
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'base.User'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'collectfast',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'primeiraAplicacaoDjango.base',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'primeiraAplicacaoDjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'primeiraAplicacaoDjango.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

default_db_url = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')

parse_database = partial(dj_database_url.parse, conn_max_age=600)

DATABASES = {
    'default': config('DATABASE_URL', default=default_db_url, cast=parse_database)
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Config da Django-debug-toolbar
INTERNAL_IPS = config('INTERNAL_IPS', cast=Csv(), default='127.0.0.1')
if DEBUG:
    INSTALLED_APPS.append('debug_toolbar')
    MIDDLEWARE.insert(0, 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

# Configuração de ambiente de desenvolvimento

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')

COLLECTFAST_ENABLED = False


def show_toolbar(request):
    return True


SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK = show_toolbar

mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    "INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS": False,
}

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
COLLECTFAST_STRATEGY = 'collectfast.strategies.boto3.Boto3Strategy'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')

# STORAGE CONFIGURATION FOR S3 AWS
# ---------------------------------

if AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400', }
    AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
    AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = False
    AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = None
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'private'
    COLLECTFAST_ENABLED = True

    # static assets
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 's3_folder_storage.s3.StaticStorage'
    STATIC_S3_PATH = 'static'
    STATIC_ROOT = f'/{STATIC_S3_PATH}/'
    STATIC_URL = f'//s3.amazonaws.com/{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}/{STATIC_S3_PATH}/'
    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

    # Upload Media Folder
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 's3_folder_storage.s3.DefaultStorage'
    DEFAULT_S3_PATH = 'media'
    MEDIA_ROOT = f'/{DEFAULT_S3_PATH}/'
    MEDIA_URL = f'//s3.amazonaws.com/{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}/{{DEFAULT_S3_PATH}}/'

    INSTALLED_APPS.append('s3_folder_storage')
    INSTALLED_APPS.append('storages')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render # noqa
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('<html><body>Olá Django!</body></html>', content_type='text/html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include
from django.conf import settings
from primeiraAplicacaoDjango.base.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns.append(
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer last month, forgot to post here, it was actually a weird error on my settings.py that somehow was solved by copying and pasting the same code again